# POST request gives 404, GET request works

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My AJAX request gives a 404 on POST but when I change it to GET it works fine. Why is this?

```
$('#navitem').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var level = $(this).attr('lvl');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'subjects.php',
        data: { "subjid": level },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: String,
        complete: function () {
            // window.location = 'subjects.php';
        }
    });
});
```

Both the pages are present in the same directory.

Comment: What is the code in `subjects.php`? Also note that your `dataType` setting is incorrect.

Comment: is normal core php or any MVC ?

Comment: @JYoThI `type: 'POST'` should be fine

Comment: @JYoThI nope, it's `type` in a jQuery AJAX request. The attribute is named `method` on a `form` element though

Comment: Did anyone ever read docs? `method` and `type` are the same (`type` is just an alias) - since jQuery 1.9 - lower versions should use `type`

Comment: Would be good to see the code inside the subjects.php

Comment: @JYoThI From the [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L532): `s.type = options.method || options.type || s.method || s.type;`

Comment: @dinesh it is normal core php

Comment: $subjid=$_POST['subjid'];
echo $subjid;
this is the data inside subjects.php

Comment: I thought there are some bug in subjects.php